# UI for Setting up a Checking account and Savings account for my bank project

Tags: c++

I want to display an interface asking the user whether or not they want to use checkings or savings account, and then when they choose bring them to my generic display menu. But I'm not quite sure how to set it up. I was told to make Account objects and use a pointer, but as you can see I'm stuck. If anyone could give me any insight on how I would do this, I would greatly appreciate it.

Here is my code:

```
#ifndef ACCOUNT_H 
#define ACCOUNT_H 

class Account 
{ 
private: 
  double balance; // Account balance 
  double interestRate; // Interest rate for the period 
  double interest; // Interest earned for the period 
  int transactions; // Number of transactions 

public: 
  Account(double iRate = 0.045, double bal = 0) 
  { balance = bal; 
    interestRate = iRate; 
    interest = 0; 
    transactions = 0; } 

  void setInterestRate(double iRate) 
  { interestRate = iRate; } 

  void makeDeposit(double amount) 
  { balance += amount; transactions++; } 

  bool withdraw(double amount); // Defined in Account.cpp 

  void calcInterest() 
  { interest = balance * interestRate; balance += interest; } 

  double getInterestRate() const 
  { return interestRate; }

  double getBalance() const 
  { return balance; } 

  double getInterest() const 
  { return interest; }     

  int getTransactions() const 
  { return transactions; } 

}; 

#endif
```

```
int main() 
{ 
  Account Savings;
  Account Checkings;
  Account *ptr;

  Account savings; // Savings account object 

  char choice; // Menu selection 

  // Set numeric output formatting. 
  cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2); 

  do 
  { 
    // Display the menu and get a valid selection. 
    displayMenu(); 

    cin >> choice; 

    while (toupper(choice) < 'A' || toupper(choice) > 'G') 
    { 
      cout << "Please make a choice in the range " << "of A through G:"; 
      cin >> choice; 
    } 

    // Process the user's menu selection. 
    switch(choice) 
    { 
      case 'a': 
      case 'A': cout << "The current balance is $"; 
        cout << savings.getBalance() << endl; 
        break; 
      case 'b': 
      case 'B': cout << "There have been "; 
        cout << savings.getTransactions() << " transactions.\n";
        break; 
      case 'c': 
      case 'C': cout << "Interest earned for this period: $"; 
        cout << savings.getInterest() << endl; 
        break; 
      case 'd': 
      case 'D': makeDeposit(savings); 
        break; 
      case 'e': 
      case 'E': withdraw(savings); 
        break; 
      case 'f': 
      case 'F': savings.calcInterest(); 
        cout << "Interest added.\n"; 
    }
  } while (toupper(choice) != 'G'); 
return 0; 
} 

void displayMenu() 
{ 
  cout << "\n Welcome to The Bank \n"; 
  cout << "-----------------------------------------\n"; 
  cout << "A) Display the account balance\n"; 
  cout << "B) Display the number of transactions\n"; 
  cout << "C) Display interest earned for this period\n"; 
  cout << "D) Make a deposit\n"; 
  cout << "E) Make a withdrawal\n"; 
  cout << "F) Add interest for this period\n"; 
  cout << "G) Exit the program\n\n"; 
  cout << "Enter your choice: "; 
} 

void makeDeposit(Account *acct)
{
  double dollars; 

  cout << "Enter the amount of the deposit: "; 

  cin >> dollars;
  cin.ignore(); 

  acct.makeDeposit(dollars);
}

void withdraw(Account *acct)
{
  double dollars;

  cout << "Enter the amount of the withdrawal: "; 

  cin >> dollars; 
  cin.ignore(); 

  if (!acct.withdraw(dollars)) 
    cout << "ERROR: Withdrawal amount too large.\n\n";
}
```

Comment: I suggest investing in '.' in your description.  Looks like one long sentence.

Comment: You can save a lot of code by converting `choice` to upper case or lower case before the `switch` statement.  See `std::toupper` or `std::tolower`.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
char displayAccountSelectionMenu();
char displayAccountActionMenu();
void makeDeposit(Account *acct);
void withdraw(Account *acct);

int main() 
{ 
    Account Savings;
    Account Checkings;
    Account *acct = NULL;

    char choice; // Menu selection 

    do
    {
        // Display the menu and get a valid selection. 
        choice = displayAccountSelectionMenu();

        // Process the user's menu selection. 
        switch (choice)
        {
            case 'A':
                acct = &Savings;
                break;

             case 'B':
                acct = &Checkings;
                break;

             case 'C':
                return 0;
        }

        // Set numeric output formatting. 
        cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2); 

        do 
        { 
            // Display the menu and get a valid selection. 
            choice = displayAccountActionMenu(); 

            // Process the user's menu selection. 
            switch (choice) 
            { 
                case 'A':
                    cout << "The current balance is $"
                         << acct->getBalance() << endl; 
                    break; 

                case 'B':
                    cout << "There have been "
                         << acct->getTransactions() 
                         << " transactions." << endl;
                    break; 

                case 'C':
                    cout << "Interest earned for this period: $"
                         << acct->getInterest() << endl; 
                    break; 

                case 'D':
                    makeDeposit(acct); 
                    break; 

                case 'E':
                    withdraw(acct); 
                    break; 

                case 'F':
                    acct->calcInterest(); 
                    cout << "Interest added." << endl; 
                    break;

                case 'G':
                    break;

                case 'H':
                    return 0;
            } 
        }
        while (choice != 'G'); 
    }
    while (true);

    return 0; 
} 

char displayAccountSelectionMenu()
{
    char choice;

    cout << "\n Welcome to The Bank \n"; 
    cout << "-----------------------------------------\n"; 
    cout << "Select an account:\n";
    cout << "A) Savings\n"; 
    cout << "B) Checking\n"; 
    cout << "C) Exit the program\n\n"; 
    cout << "Enter your choice: "; 

    cin >> choice; 
    choice = toupper(choice);

    while ((choice < 'A') || (choice > 'C'))
    { 
        cout << "Please make a choice in the range of A through C:"; 
        cin >> choice; 
        choice = toupper(choice);
    } 

    return choice;
}

char displayAccountActionMenu() 
{ 
    char choice;

    cout << "\n Welcome to The Bank \n"; 
    cout << "-----------------------------------------\n"; 
    cout << "Select an action:\n";
    cout << "A) Display the account balance\n"; 
    cout << "B) Display the number of transactions\n"; 
    cout << "C) Display interest earned for this period\n"; 
    cout << "D) Make a deposit\n"; 
    cout << "E) Make a withdrawal\n"; 
    cout << "F) Add interest for this period\n"; 
    cout << "G) Select a different account\n"; 
    cout << "H) Exit the program\n\n"; 
    cout << "Enter your choice: "; 

    cin >> choice; 
    choice = toupper(choice);

    while ((choice < 'A') || (choice > 'H'))
    { 
        cout << "Please make a choice in the range of A through H:"; 
        cin >> choice; 
        choice = toupper(choice);
    } 

    return choice;
} 

void makeDeposit(Account *acct)
{
    //...
}

void withdraw(Account *acct)
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Error 2 error C3861: 'displayAccountActionMenu': identifier not found l:\bank account project\bank account project\main.cpp 57 1 Bank Account project

Comment: Error 1 error C3861: 'displayAccountSelectionMenu': identifier not found l:\bank account project\bank account project\main.cpp 34 1 Bank Account project
getting these errors with that code any fix?

Comment: Obviously, you would have to declare `displayAccountSelectionMenu()` and `displayAccountActionMenu()` before using them.  I gave you the implementations for them, thinking you would understand that.  You did not show any of your function declarations.  I have updated my answer to include the declarations.

Comment: sorry its always the little things that get me lol im new to c++.

Comment: i added in my header file so you could see where i declare my functions.

Comment: Your standalone `makeDeposit()` and `withdraw()` functions take an `Account*` pointer as input (which is fine), but you are using `acct.` to call the Account methods (which is not fine). You need to use `acct->` instead: `acct->makeDeposit(dollars);` and `if (!acct->withdraw(dollars))`.  Also, you are implementing the body of the `Account` methods inline in the `.h` file, except for `withdraw()` which is implemented in the .cpp file. You should implement *all* of the method bodies in the .cpp file.